# Does "operator true" in c# have exactly two places it can be used?

Tags: c#, boolean, operator-overloading

c# lets you override "operator true" and "operator false" for a class:

```
class Foo
{
   bool Thing;

   Foo(bool thing)
   {
      Thing = thing;
   }

   public static bool operator true(Foo foo) => foo.Thing;
   public static bool operator false(Foo foo) => !foo.Thing;
}
```

and it sort of works.  You can say

```
Foo foo = new Foo(true);
if (foo)
   Stuff();
string s = foo ? "yes" : "no";
```

But you can't say

```
Foo foo = new Foo(true);
bool boo = true;
if (boo && foo)
   Stuff();
if (boo & foo)
   Stuff();
if (boo & (foo == true))
   Stuff();
if (boo & ((bool)foo))
   Stuff();
Foo foo2 = new Foo(true);
if (foo && foo2)
   Stuff();
if (foo & foo2)
   Stuff();
if (foo == boo)
   Stuff();
if (foo != boo)
   Stuff();
bool boo2 = foo;
```

In every case the compiler complains.

Does the c# compiler use "operator true" and "operator false" anywhere except for those very specific syntaxes?

EDIT

I found one more place where "operator true" and "operator false" work.  If you define an "operator&" that returns Foo in addition to the true and false operators, the compiler will take an expression "foo1 && foo2" and pretend you wrote "foo1 & foo2" and so call your overridden operator.  In other words, the existence of "operator true" and "operator false" change the compiler's behavior *even though it never calls those operators*.

Comment: Why do you expect operator true to overload other not related operators like &, explicit casts like (bool)?

Comment: Have you tried `boo == foo` or `boo != foo`

Comment: Good question @Çöđěxěŕ - and the answer is - it doesn't compile

Comment: The statement `if (boo && foo)` has to cast both boo and foo to bool, and the class Foo does not implement the required implicit cast. For the other statements to work (where the bitwise operators are used), you should implement the & and | operators.

Comment: I'm not trying to get these other statements to work; I'm trying to understand why "operator true" and "operator false" even exist.  You're right - doing an implicit cast makes pretty much all those statements compile - so why did the language designers create "operator true" and "operator false"?

Comment: @BettyCrokker See the latest edit to my answer for why the last statement in your edit is not true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does “operator true” in c# have exactly two places it can be used?

Not exactly. You can search on the [C# Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) for "operator true" (I did) and see what it does. Sections [7.12.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#user-defined-conditional-logical-operators), [7.14](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#conditional-operator), [7.20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#boolean-expressions) mentions it. 7.14 essentially is about the ternary operator which you already know about, but in 7.20, it says

> A `boolean-expression` is an expression that yields a result of type
>   bool; either directly or through application of operator `true` in
>   certain contexts as specified in the following.
>
> The controlling conditional expression of an `if-statement` (§8.7.1),
>   `while-statement` (§8.8.1), `do-statement` (§8.8.2), or `for-statement`
>   (§8.8.3) is a `boolean-expression`.

So, not just in an `if` statement, but also in a `while`, `do`, `for` as well.

In 7.12.2, it says:

> When the operands of `&&` or `||` are of types that declare an applicable
>   user-defined operator `&` or operator `|`, both of the following must be
>   true, where `T` is the type in which the selected operator is declared:
>
> - The return type and the type of each parameter of the selected operator must be `T`. In other words, the operator must compute the
>     logical AND or the logical OR of two operands of type `T`, and must
>     return a result of type `T`.
> - `T` must contain declarations of operator `true` and operator `false`.

So `&&` *can* be used on your custom type if you also declare `&`.

---

EDIT:

Just found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/true-false-operators), which sums it up very clearly.

---

> In other words, the existence of "operator true" and "operator false" change the compiler's behavior even though it never calls those operators.

It *does* call these operators. As per the language spec 7.12.2:

> The operation `x && y` is evaluated as `T.false(x) ? x : T.&(x, y)`, where `T.false(x)` is an invocation of the operator `false` declared in `T`, and `T.&(x, y)` is an invocation of the selected operator `&`. In other words, `x` is first evaluated and operator `false` is invoked on the result to determine if `x` is definitely `false`. Then, if `x` is definitely `false`, the result of the operation is the value previously computed for `x`. Otherwise, `y` is evaluated, and the selected operator `&` is invoked on the value previously computed for `x` and the value computed for `y` to produce the result of the operation.

Basically, since `&&` is short-circuiting, it has to know whether one of its operand is false, by using the `false` operator.

> so why did the language designers create "operator true" and "operator false"?

It's explained pretty well [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/true-false-operators), I think:

> The `true` operator returns the bool value `true` to indicate that its operand is definitely true. The `false` operator returns the bool value `true` to indicate that its operand is definitely false.

It's basically for situations where you want your custom type to have a truthy/falsey value. The `LaunchStatus` type in the same link and the `DBBool` type [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs#database-boolean-type) are good examples of this.

Comment: Aha!  So I would sum up the answer like this: "operator true and operator false, by themselves, are not terribly useful.  But if you also define the implicit cast to bool and override operator| and operator&, then you get something cool"

Comment: @BettyCrokker I've tried to answer the "why" question in the edit.

Comment: I think you would be hard pressed to find any production code that implemented "operator true" and "operator false" without any of the other overrides.  But it makes perfect sense why you would create them in order to make the other features work, you've explained it very well - thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted all of those conditional statements to compile, then you need to implement more operators in addition to `true` and `false`. You could get them all to work with this implementation:

```
public class Foo
{
    bool Thing;

    public Foo(bool thing)
    {
        Thing = thing;
    }

    public static bool operator true(Foo foo) => foo;
    public static bool operator false(Foo foo) => !foo;
    public static implicit operator bool(Foo foo) => foo?.Thing ?? false;
    public static implicit operator Foo(bool b) => new Foo(b);
    public static Foo operator &(Foo left, Foo right) => (left?.Thing & right?.Thing) ?? false;
    public static Foo operator |(Foo left, Foo right) => (left?.Thing | right?.Thing) ?? false;
}
```

Now, if you were to remove the `true` and `false` operators, you would see that the short-circuit operations, `if(boo && foo)` and `if(foo && foo2)` would no longer compile. As @Sweeper wrote in his answer, those operators are necessary in order to get short-circuited expressions to compile.