# C#: Difference between implicit bool cast and operator true/false

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I am trying to understand the usage of overloading the true/false operator and I stumbled upon the following behaviour:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public TestClass(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public static bool operator true(TestClass testClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("USING TRUE!");
        return (testClass.X == 1 && testClass.Y == 1);
    }

    public static bool operator false(TestClass testClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("USING FALSE!");
        return (testClass.X != 1 || testClass.Y != 1);
    }

    //public static implicit operator bool(TestClass testClass)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("USING CAST!");
    //    return (testClass.X == 5);
    //}
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass x = new TestClass(5, 2);


        if (x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("X is true!");
        }
    }
}
```

The example without the implicit conversion overload prints the following:

```
USING TRUE!
```

The example with the implicit conversion overload prints the following:

```
USING CAST!
X is true!
```

Therefore my question is: What is the difference between both operators?
Or as this might be too imprecise more specific: What happens behind the scenes? Why is the true operator used in the first example, but the conversion in the second?
I'd like to understand when the compiler uses the true/false operator, so I can figure out when they should be overloaded. The C# Documentation helped a bit, but not enough, for me to fully understand.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674675/does-operator-true-in-c-sharp-have-exactly-two-places-it-can-be-used/60674882#60674882) answer your question? See my answer, where I described all the places where operator true is used.

Comment: To add to @Sweeper's linked answer, [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#boolean-expressions) explains that an implicit conversion to `bool` is attempted before looking for `operator true` / `operator false`

Comment: Sweeper's linked answer helps me understand the first half of the question. @canton7 helps with the second half. But Are there cases, where the true/false operator are used eventhough the bool cast exists?

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/true-false-operators#boolean-expressions) says that `operator true` is used in `if`, `do`, `while`, `for` and `?:`. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#boolean-expressions) says that an implicit conversion to bool is done first in `if`, `while`, `do`, `for` and `?:`. So, no: according to the spec, in all cases where `operator true` is used, an implicit conversion to bool is checked first

Comment: @canton7 Ah thanks! The same counts for `false operator`? I know it is used in `operator &&` for example together with `operator &` as seen in Sweepers answer. I'll test it myself in a sec.

Comment: Actually, I missed the bit of the spec which says that `operator true` and be used with conditional logical operators

Comment: @canton it seems like `x && y` translates to something like `T.false(x) ? T.boolConv(x) : T.boolConv(x & y)` and therefore will use the false operator, even though the implicit conversion is implemented. Same counts for `x || y`